# Python - beautifulSoup unable to iterate repetitive blocks

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Unsure how to properly word the issue.

I am trying to parse through an HTML document with a tree similar to that of

```
div(unique-class)
|-a
|-h4
|-div(class-a)
|-div(class-b)
|-div(class-c)
|-p
```

Etc, it continues. I only listed the few items I need. It is a lot of sibling hierarchy, all existing within one div.

I've been working quite a bit with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for the past few hours, and I finally have a working version (Beta) of what I'm trying to parse, in this example.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv
file = "C:\\Python27\\demo.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup (open(file), 'html.parser')
#(page, 'html.parser')

#Let's pull prices
names = []
pricing = []
discounts = []

for name in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'unique_class'}):
 names.append(name.h4.text)
for price in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'class-b'}):
 pricing.append(price.text)
for discount in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'class-a'}):
 discounts.append(discount.text)
ofile = open('output2.csv','wb')
fieldname = ['name', 'discountPrice', 'originalPrice']
writer = csv.DictWriter(ofile, fieldnames = fieldname)
writer.writeheader()
for i in range(len(names)):
 print (names[i], pricing[i], discounts[i])

 writer.writerow({'name': names[i], 'discountPrice':pricing[i], 'originalPrice': discounts[i]})
ofile.close()
```

As you can tell this it iterating from top to bottom and appending to a distinct array for each one. The issue is, if I'm iterating over, let's say, 30,000 items and the website can modify itself (We'll say a `ScoreBoard` app on a JS Framework), by the time I get to the 2nd iteration, the order may have changed. (As I type this I realize this scenario actually would need more variables since BS would 'catch' the website at time of load, but I think the point still stands.)

I believe I need to leverage the `next_sibling` function within BS4 but when I did that I started capturing items I wasn't specifying, because I couldn't apply a 'class' to the sibling.

**Update**

An additional issue I encouraged when trying to do a loop within a loop to find the 3 children I need under the `unique-class` was I would end up with the first price being listed for all names.

**Update - Adding sample HTML**

```
 <div class="unique_class">
  <h4>World</h4>
  <div class="class_b">$1.99</div>
  <div class="class_a">$1.99</div>
 </div>
 <div class="unique_class">
  <h4>World2</h4>
  <div class="class_b">$2.99</div>
  <div class="class_a">$2.99</div>
 </div>
 <div class="unique_class">
  <h4>World3</h4>
  <div class="class_b">$3.99</div>
  <div class="class_a">$3.99</div>
 </div>
 <div class="unique_class">
  <h4>World4</h4>
  <div class="class_b">$4.99</div>
  <div class="class_a">$3.99</div>
 </div>
```

I have also found a fix, and submitted the answer to be Optimized - Located at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169322/first-python-script-web-scraper-with-results-saved-to-mysql-db)

Comment: Have you actually tried calling `(open(url)...` instead of `(open(file)...`? The `soup` variable shouldn't change once it's been defined---the object BeautifulSoup creates is static.

Comment: For me at least a somewhat difficult question to answer because I can't examine the actual HTML that you want to parse. Also, although you say this is working code I doubt that the line `soup = BeautifulSoup (open(file), 'html.parser')` will do what you might expect. What specific outputs do you want?

Comment: @BillBell Completely fair point - I had to do a lot of manipulating to get html.parser as I wanted it. Attached sample, and code review link for the band-aid version I got.

Answer (score 1):

If the site you are looking to scrape the data from is using JS you may want to use selenium and use its page_source method to extract snapshots of the page with loaded JS you can then load into BS.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(<url>)
page = driver.page_source
```

Then you can use BS to parse the JS loaded 'page'
If you want to wait for other JS events to load up you are able to specify events to wait for in selenium.